# How do I have a video size for desktop without affecting mobile?

Tags: video, iframe, mobile, desktop

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.  My video on my mobile is perfect; however on desktop the video size is too large. How do I resize the video on desktop without affecting it on mobile?  The website is https://vismedics.com/collections/neck-massagers/products/shiatsu-infrared-heat-massager?variant=34940734374041.

Comment: Can you post some code? And show us what you've tried?

Comment: Says "Page Not Found".. Show code of how you put (setup) a video object on the page and how you currently "size" it. Are you using percentages or hard-coded numbers?